# Query finding a group whose members match exactly with a given string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

First of all, my English is not good, I apologize if I am rude.
I need your help with a query. I tried many things but failed.

I’ve written a little database example below.
I want to find the group whose members match exactly with the given username array.

`groups.findOne( { 'members.username': { $in: [ 'john22', 'david7' ] } } )`

As a result, the first group is returning. But there is another user in the first group. Whereas the array matches exactly with the second group. How should I write the query for exact match. Please help me.

Thank you

```
{ groups: [

  {

    id:1,

    name:"aliens",

    members:[

      {

        username:"john22",

        joineddate:222222222,

        removed: false

      },

      {

        username:"david7",

        joineddate:3333333333,

        removed: false

      },

      {

        username:"william4",

        joineddate:444444444444,

        removed: false

      },

    ]

  },

  {

    id:2,

    name:"stars",

    members:[

      {

        username:"john22",

        joineddate:111111111111,

        removed: false

      },

      {

        username:"david7",

        joineddate:111111111111,

        removed: false

      },

    ]

  }

] }
```

Comment: use $all: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

Comment: groups.find({'members.username':{$all:[ 'john22', 'david7' ]}}) I tried this but both objects are listed.

Comment: Ah, good point. I thought there was an operator for "contain exactly, no more no less" and can't find it now. But looks like you can pair `$all` with `$size` to achieve pretty much the same effect.

Comment: Yes that is great.